# Symlinking problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, phusion

Hey dudes.i am having this problem while symlinking. I have successfully deployed a ruby on rails application on server and all the migrations are done. It is deployed with phusion passenger. The application is in `/home/username/rails_apps/myapp`. I want to symlink it to a subdomain in my site. the path to subdomain is `/home/username/public_html/subdom`. So i used this command to symlink it.
`ln -s '/home/username/rails_apps/myapp/public/' '/home/username/public_html/subdom'`

when it is done, it creates `http://subdom.maxsy.net/public`
but it is supposed to be accessible by `http://subdom.maxsy.net/`

anybody have a sensible explanation for this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `/home/username/public_html/subdom` already exists as a directory, the symlink does not replace the directory: instead, you get `/home/username/public_html/subdom/public` as a symlink pointing to `/home/username/rails_app/myapp`.

Since it appears that you really do want to replace `/home/username/public_html/subdom` by the symlink, you must first remove the `/home/username/public_html/subdom` directory before running `ln -s /home/username/rails_app/myapp /home/username/public_html/subdom`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have one extra `/`, and possibly an existing `subdom`

```
rm -f /home/username/public_html/subdom
ln -s /home/username/rails_apps/myapp/public /home/username/public_html/subdom
```